# Send mail with javamail without user and password

Tags: android, email, passwords, send

I followed this post [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) to send mails without intents. it works ok. but my question is if you can send mail without having to enter your user and password? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't**

As you can see from the code, The `username` and `password` is used to login to that mail ID and then that `Email ID` is used to send the Email

The GMailSender has a constructor that takes in the username and password, this is used to create a login session as in code

```
session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
```

Once the login has been done now your sending the Email from that mail ID as you normally do in browser

***Alternatives***

Now if you want to send a email then you can send an intent in android like this

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@gmail.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client"));
```

But this would pop up the user with the choice of client from which email has to be sent

**OR**

If you even dont want to use this, then I would suggest creating your own `webserver` and make `HTTP` request to it to send Emails via the server